# React-Navigation v5 can't import bottom tab

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

On React-Navigation v4 you could do `import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';` to get the BottomTabBar so you can customize it yourself. What's the equivalent for v5, can't find anything in docs.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator).

First you have to install `bottom-tabs` :

> npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs

Then, you have to import `createBottomTabNavigator` from `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` :

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
```

Then you can create tabs. For ex :

```js
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: I need a custom tab bar. I've read the doc. What I meant is `import { createBottomTabNavigator, BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';` you could do that and import the BottomTabBar before, and what would be the equivalent in v5

Comment: For custom tab bar there is a prop called `tabBar`. You have to pass your custom tabbar in that props.

Comment: Yeah man it's in my question, I know. Do you know how to get my current tab bar element and add another one? Basically what I need is the default tabbar I get and I'll add another extra view on top of it for some cases when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

You import `import { BottomTabBar } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';` from the new package, but be careful, when using it in your navigation you have to pass it the props otherwise it throws an error. The pattern would be

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="..."
  tabBar={props => <CustomBottomTab {...props} />}
  tabBarOptions={...}>
```